# Rich text editor - losing carriage returns in headings

Tags: richtext

Carriage returns (ctrl-enter or coded br tags) work fine in paragraphs but they're not saving in the middle of a h1 heading.

Has anyone else encountered this or am I taking crazy pills?

Thanks
Amanda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with pixel and tonic wygwam.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is third party. The included RTE has a multitude of bugs EL just seems to keep ignoring.